# Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /usr/share/tomcat9/conf. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat9

I am using JSP for the 1st time. I am using tomcat9. While creating server, from eclipse, I get a window which shows Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /usr/share/tomcat9/conf. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete. Attached is the screenshot.
[image: adding server]
[image: error]

I installed 2 versions of tomcat9, but the error still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an installed copy of Tomcat, its layout will have been modified and you won't have full read-write control over it. Use the tar/zip file you can download from tomcat.apache.org.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux ubuntu, I went to the directory-> `/usr/share/tomcat9/` by

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat9/
```

but conf folder is not there
My default installation path was `/opt/tomcat/latest/`
conf folder is inside that
So, I created a symbolic link from  `/usr/share/tomcat9/` to `/opt/tomcat/latest/conf`
I did `cd /usr/share/tomcat9/`
Then

```
sudo ln -s /opt/tomcat/latest/conf conf
```

Now everything worked and I can run helloworld program
To help others facing same problem->
Just find the conf folder and create a link to that folder
In windows create a shortcut; and in linux create a symbolink link.
In Linux:

```
sudo locate tomcat>>a.txt
vi a.txt
```

then search for conf in a.txt

```
/conf
```

identify a line containing both tomcat and conf
Find the location where system is searching for conf, in the error message.
For me, it was `/usr/share/tomcat9/`
Then link both the folders by creating symbolic link using ln -s command

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your eclipse on command line then look if something goes wrong.
In my case, when a pressed New Server - Tomcat9:

> [Fatal Error] :19:10: Element type "Context" must be followed by
> either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Then, i check my context.xml and find something like (line 19):

<Context "privileged=true">

Just remove "privileged=true" and now works :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).